# Puppet not showing docker running server

Tags: docker, puppet

I am trying puppet to run a docker container. I am using puppetlabs docker module. Everything is working fine but the run command is not working, despite everything is fine in puppet log and shows running.

```
==> default: Running Puppet with default.pp...
==> default: Notice: Compiled catalog for pustakalaya.vm.vm.local in environment production in 0.52 seconds
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Pustakalaya::Installdocker/Exec[install docker]/returns: executed successfully
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Docker::Repos/Apt::Source[docker]/Apt::Setting[list-docker]/File[/etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list]/content: content changed '{md5}c4955fdae0865aac860821ca9257f48b' to '{md5}395ee27d70d138f3f6bdf37acbbb5c4f'
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Apt::Update/Exec[apt_update]: Triggered 'refresh' from 1 event
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Pustakalaya::Installdocker/Service[docker]: Triggered 'refresh' from 1 event
==> default: Notice: /Stage[main]/Pustakalaya::Run/Docker::Run[nginx]/Service[docker-nginx]/ensure: ensure changed 'stopped' to 'running'
```

My puppet class is

```
docker::run { 'nginx':
    image   => 'nginx:latest',
          detach  => true,
          ports => ['80:80'],
          command => "/bin/bash"
   }
```

EDIT solution

According to github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-docker/issues/313 On an os using systemd you don't need the detatch => true param set. If you remove it the example you've provide will run without any issues

Comment: most likely you already have something listening on port 80 and this made the container die:  `docker ps -a` on the host and see if the container did indeed exit

Comment: @UkuLoskit  No, there is no any in docker ps -a. Also, port 80 is not used. when I try docker command it works

Comment: @Bikram, if you have found a solution yourself and would like to share it (thanks!) then the customary way to do so around here is to write and post an actual answer to the question.  Editing the solution into the question is inconsistent with our model and conventions.

Answer (score 0):

The container lives for as long as the command you're running.

In your case it most likely runs a non-interactive call to bash successfully and exits with 0.

To keep the container running you'd want to pass the --interactive param to docker. Looking at the [puppet docker docs](https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/docker#containers) it sounds like you can add `extra_parameters => ['--interactive'],` to your docker::run.

Comment: I removed  **detach  => true**  and it worked. I don't understand the issue here. But anyway thanks

Comment: According to https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-docker/issues/313 On an os using systemd you don't need the detatch => true param set. If you remove it the example you've provide will run without any issues.